# iOS won't load content from htaccess / htpasswd-protected subdomains

Tags: ios, apache, .htaccess, ios5, .htpasswd

Because my site is in an early beta-stage, I have added a htaccess-protection to it to prevent  random users, searchbots etc. to see the (unfinished) page.

I did it like this:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Everything worked fine now for months, until today I added 2 subdomains like

img.domain.com

and

static.domain.com

as a workaround for the get-request limit of browsers which applies per domain/subdomain.

Now everything works as expected except on my iOS 6 iPhone 5, which only asks for the password for www.domain.com and img.domain.com, but not for static.domain.com and therefor won't ever load those resources.

Can anyone confirm this behavior? Thanks.

**More info**

I can see in the safari debuger that those resources from one of the subdomain (seems to be random which one) are not downloaded. They go red when I stop the pageload.

**Even more info**

I just confirmed that removing the above Auth-Block from htaccess makes everything work, so in my opinion, this is simply a bug of iOS(6). I'd be glad if anyone can confirm this, although I won't have the problem once the site is live anyway.